# How to retrieve the port of a vagrant instance?

Tags: vagrant

`vagrant` instances setup SSH servers with variable ports (depending on the next available - and possilby some other conditions) when they're initialized. The port can be retrieved with `vagrant ssh-config`, but there's no way to retrieve the port without parsing the output. How to parse the output reliably?

I created [a feature request for `vagrant`](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5696) to solve this within `vagrant`.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
vagrant ssh-config | grep Port | cut -d ' ' -f 4
```

works